# Вывод множественного списка в MODX

Tags: modx

Мне нужно выводить ссылки определенных списков ресурсов.
Я делаю так:

- Создаю отдельное поле с названием `testpole` с множественным списком.
- В возможные значения вбиваю запрос к бд `@SELECT pagetitle, id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent=7`

Но дальше я не знаю как вывести `url` этих ресурсов в шаблон... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Ещё интересует вопрос, как связать это с MIGX. 
Мне нужно в MIGX добавлять поле с одним ресурсом и рядом с ним писать цену.
Чтобы нажать "добавить элемент", выбрать один из ресурсов, присвоить ему цену вторым значением и вывести это таблицей в чанк.

Как связать поля я разобрался, просто добавляю в формы MIGX {"field":"res","caption":"Выбор ресурсов","inputTV":"testpole"} , но вот как вывести их - нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, на вкладке *Параметры вывода*, у доп. поля `testpole` ставим разделитель `,`

На выходе мы получим, при выводе в шаблоне список через запятую из `id` нужных нам ресурсов.

Затем, можно полученный список поместить в параметр `&resources`, сниппета `pdoResources`

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &parents=`0`
    &resources=`[[*testpole]]`
    &depth=`0`
    &tpl=`link.tpl`
]]
```

В чанке `link.tpl` соответственно, формируем ссылку, как требуется, например:

```
<li><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></li>
```

---

**upd:**
Чтобы избежать отработки `pdoResources` в случаи, если `testpole` не заполнено, предварительно можно проверять это поле, например с помощью модификатора:

```
[[*testpole:notempty=`
  [[!pdoResources?
    &parents=`0`
    &resources=`[[*testpole]]`
    &depth=`0`
    &tpl=`link.tpl`
  ]]
`]]
```

Или писать отдельный сниппет. Хотя, этого решения должно быть достаточно.

---

По **MIGX**, как вы и пробовали следует использовать `getImageList`, примерно так:

```
[[getImageList?
    &docid=`[[*id]]`
    &tvname=`имя migx поля`
    &tpl=`tpl.migx`
]]
```

В `tpl.migx`, цену выводим, как обычно (это наверно у вас получилось), а доступ к значениям передаваемого `id` ресурса (`testpole`) можно осуществить с помощью всё того же шаблонизатора *fenom*. Примерно так в итоге:

```
<li><a href="[[#[[+res]].uri]]">[[#[[+res]].pagetitle]]</a> - Цена: [[+price]]</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю!) Если работает, то Вы, Александр, не первый раз меня выручите :)

Comment: Работает, но не совсем так, как нужно. Если не выбирать поле из админки, pdoResources формирует все ресурсы из родителя. Не подскажите, как проверять этот момент? 

И ещё один момент: я пытаюсь связать поле с migx,
{"field":"res","caption":"Выбор ресурсов","inputTV":"testpole"} , в админке поле выбирается, но как его вывести в чанке ?
Пытался через getImageList и pdoresourse - не получилось :(

Comment: @Александр обновил ответ. Про `migx` не очень понятно, что в итоге Вы хотите, и как это связано с выводом списка ресурсов через `pdoResources`. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, или, если это не связанные задачи, то сформулируйте новый.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Александр обновил по `migx`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё получилось. Правда синтаксис не понял, откуда uri берется. Это выборка поля из таблицы в бд? Сейчас заметил, что ссылка на ресурс не выводится с помощью migx - она ведет на главную...

Comment: `uri` возвращает адрес ресурса. По сути это аналог `[[~[[+id]]]]`, только берёт адрес напрямую из бд, без формирования его с помощью `makeUrl()`

Comment: [[#[[+res]].uri]] не выводит url почему-то..

Comment: а что возвращает `[[+res]]`? В чанке, который указывается в `getImageList` оставьте только `[[+res]]`, что то мне подсказывает что там не id-ресурса.

Comment: [[+res]] возвращает id ресурса..

Comment: тогда, всё таки надо пробовать `[[~[[+res]]]]` вместо `[[#[[+res]].uri]]`

Comment: И это точно, спасибо огромное!

Comment: И ещё один вопрос, если Вас не затруднит ответить..
@SELECT pagetitle, id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent=7 выводит только один уровень вложенности. Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы выводились все дочерние элементы ?

Comment: @Александр Ну соответственно выбирать из нескольких родителей, например: `@SELECT pagetitle, id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent IN (7, 10, 15)` где в скобках это список `id` родителей, ресурсы из которых надо выводить. Либо например, ресурсам, которые надо выводить назначить общий шаблон, и тогда условие будет `WHERE template=5`, где 5 - это `id` общего шаблона.

Comment: А динамически нельзя сделать? Только вручную указывать ?

Comment: Разобрался только через конфигуратор MIGX и resourcelist